# when running selenium tests via jenkins on headless firefox browser the screenshots captured is of 0 bytes

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, xvfb

I am running my selenium tests via Jenkins on  Headless Firefox browser on Cent OS.
I have written a code to capture screenshots on failure which works absolutley fine on my local windows environment but when I run the same script using Jenkins on CentOS the screenshot captured is of 0 bytes

Below is the Java code to capture Screenshot:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Screen_Capture {
    public static void takeDesktopScreenshot(WebDriver driver,String dateFormat,String fileFormat,String screenPath){
        File src=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            String d=s.format(new Date());
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File(screenPath+d+"."+fileFormat));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }


}
```

The Screenshots are captured on Test Failure:

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
        Screen_Capture.takeDesktopScreenshot(driver,dateFormat,fileFormat,screenPath);
        log.error("Test Case Failed");


    }

The Images saved on Jenkins Workspace is blank(0 bytes)

[Screen File Size is 0 Bytes][1]

Please help me to overcome this issue.

I am also attaching my Build Environment Configuration on Jenkins:
[Build Environment Configuration on Jenkins][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBNUD.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMxPq.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sometimes there may be permission issue with jenkins , try giving  chmod -R 777 * and also try using chown the folder which download , first try manually and try using jenkins you will know the issue easily.